# Electron windows installer Need to call batch file in between the installation and upon completion continue with the installation

Tags: windows-installer, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-window

Windows-installer package for electron([link](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer))
I want to create the installer which can copy content. 
For the specific case I want to run a batch file which will copy content. 
Upon completion of the content copy the installer next should continue installing the application

Is it possible in windows-installer ?
I am unable to find any documentation for the same?

Please note calling batch script is necessary since the external content copy logic is well defined. 
Content copy can  go upto 1 TB or more so adding it in installer itself will not work